# GitHub API limit array length to 250

Tags: limit, github-api, octokit-js

When calling the GitHub API with Octokit to get all ahead commits of a fork repo by comparing each of their branches together, if the fork repo contains more than 300 commits ahead then octokit only returns a maximum of 250. I have searched the entire Internet but still have no clue. Does anyone know how to bypass this limit? Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adding [`octokit/plugin-paginate-rest.js`](https://github.com/octokit/plugin-paginate-rest.js) in order to include pagination to your results

> The `per_page` parameter is usually defaulting to 30, and can be set to
> up to 100, which helps retrieving a big amount of data without hitting
> the rate limits too soon.
>
> An optional `mapFunction` can be passed to map each page response to a
> new value, usually an array with only the data you need.
> This can help
> to reduce memory usage, as only the relevant data has to be kept in
> memory until the pagination is complete.
>
> ```js
> const issueTitles = await octokit.paginate(
>  "GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues",
>  {
>    owner: "octocat",
>    repo: "hello-world",
>    since: "2010-10-01",
>    per_page: 100,
>  },
>  (response) => response.data.map((issue) => issue.title)
> );
> ```